# Writing the LINQ Query to search all the sub-directories?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have a solution folder in which I have collect all the .dll's and store in a array list. I have to search all the sub-directories. How to write the LINQ Query?

```
var r = dir.GetFiles("*.dll")
           .Where<FileInfo>(i => i.Name.StartsWith("SAMPLE"))
           .ToList();
```

Is this Correct? For example i 20 dll's startwith name "SAMPLE"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend you using the [EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571.aspx) method:

```
var r = Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(@"c:\work", "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(file => file.StartsWith("SAMPLE"))
    .ToList();
```

or even better use the wildcard pattern to filter instead of filtering in-memory:

```
var r = Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(@"c:\work", "SAMPLE*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: while am getting the file's am getting the duplicates also.How to remove the duplicates?

Comment: var r = Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(@"c:\work", "SAMPLE*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(a => a.Filename).Distinct().ToList();

*r* will contain a List<string> collection containing all filenames.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your LINQ is correct. It should work fine.
Small correction: you don't need the tye parameter there. (The compiler can infer it.)

```
var list = dir.GetFiles("*.dll").Where(i => i.Name.StartsWith("SAMPLE")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's correct.

I quickly created similar code to test myself and it works.

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Test");
var files = dir.GetFiles("*.jpg").Where<FileInfo>(i => i.Name.StartsWith("Tet")).ToList();

files.ForEach(file => Console.WriteLine(file.Name));
```